# Removing duplicates from the list of unicode strings

Tags: python, list, unicode-string

I am trying to remove duplicates from the list of unicode string without changing the order(So, I don't want to use set) of elements appeared in it.

**Program:**

```
result = [u'http://google.com', u'http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html', u'http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html',u'http://amazon.com', u'http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html', u'http://yahoo.com']
result.reverse()
for e in result:
    count_e = result.count(e)
    if count_e > 1:
        for i in range(0, count_e - 1):
            result.remove(e)
result.reverse()
print result
```

**Output:**

```
[u'http://google.com', u'http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html', u'http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html', u'http://amazon.com', u'http://yahoo.com']
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[u'http://google.com', u'http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html', u'http://amazon.com', u'http://yahoo.com']
```

So, Is there any way of doing it simple as possible.

Comment: Are you sure you updated the actual output? A non-unicode is still in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't have duplicates in your list. One time you have `http://catb.org` while another time you have `http://www.catb.org`.

You'll have to figure a way to determine whether the URL has `www.` in front or not.

Comment: oops... that was a mistake when copy pasting it actually it has www please check now

Comment: @Balakrishnan One has `~esr` another has `esr`

Comment: Oh... ya... sorry for that. So, I have to solve that problem now. Is there any easy way to compare whether urls directs to same page or not.

Comment: @Balakrishnan You could try looking at [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a set and then sort it by the original index:

```
sorted(set(result), key=result.index)
```

This works because `index` returns the first occurrence (so it keeps them in order according to first appearance in the original list)

I also notice that one of the strings in your original isn't a unicode string. So you might want to do something like:

```
u = [unicode(s) for s in result]
return sorted(set(u), key=u.index)
```

EDIT: `'http://google.com'` and `'http://www.google.com'` are not string duplicates. If you want to treat them as such, you could do something like:

```
def remove_www(s):
    s = unicode(s)
    prefix = u'http://'
    suffix = s[11:] if s.startswith(u'http://www') else s[7:]
    return prefix+suffix
```

And then replace the earlier code with

```
u = [remove_www(s) for s in result]
return sorted(set(u), key=u.index)
```

Comment: No, its not working it still returns `[u'http://google.com', u'http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html', u'http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html', u'http://amazon.com', 'http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html', u'http://yahoo.com']`

Comment: Also, as someone else pointed out, `www.foo.com` and `foo.com` are not treated as the same string by default.

Comment: My last comment stands. It is correctly stripping duplicate strings, it's just that there aren't any duplicate strings. So Haidro's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new list and add items to it if they're not already in it.

```
result = [ /some list items/]
uniq = []
for item in result:
    if item not in uniq:
        uniq.append(item)
```

Comment: No, its not working it still returns `[u'http://google.com', u'http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html', u'http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html', u'http://amazon.com', 'http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html', u'http://yahoo.com']`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that modifies `result` in place:

```
result = [u'http://google.com', u'http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html', u'http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html',u'http://amazon.com', 'http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html', u'http://yahoo.com']
seen = set()
i = 0
while i < len(result):
    if result[i] not in seen:
        seen.add(result[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        del result[i]
```